# SwiftUI my array is empty when it should not

Tags: arrays, xcode, csv, swiftui, fill

I've got a mistake with one of my structured array in my project.
My App is downloading value from a CSV via a web URL and then decrypt the CSV and fill my array following  structure :

```
Place(lat: ..., long: ..., Name: ..., url: ..., proximity: ...)
```

Then I go in a new view and I need to compare each data in my array to find which one is the nearest from User location using Latitude and Longitude compare.

My problem is, when I run my app I download the CSV and I split it and fill my array with this function :

```
func downloadCsvFromURL(){
    
    let placeLibrary = PlaceLibrary()
    
    let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("Images.csv")
    let fileURL = URL(string: "https://apps.e-rochoise.fr/ressources/imageTest.csv")!
  
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: fileURL) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                
                let csv = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
                for line in csv {
                    let fields = line.components(separatedBy: ";")
                    if fields.count == 4 {
                        let name = fields[0]
                        let url = fields[1]
                        let lat = fields[2].replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
                        let lon = fields[3].replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
                        print("Line - Name : \(name) - Lat : \(lat) - Long : \(lon) - URL : \(url)")
                        let newPlace = Place(lat: Double(lat)!, long: Double(lon)!, Name: name, url: ((URL(string: url)) ?? URL(string : "NIL"))!, proximity: 0.0)
                        placeLibrary.testPlace.append(newPlace)

                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            do {
                try data.write(to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch  {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print(error!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()  
}
```

This is call in the `init` of my `@main` file. After this I call this function just to see if my array is well filled :

```
func printMyArray(){
    
    let placeLibrary = PlaceLibrary()
    
    for (idx, readOnlyPlace) in placeLibrary.testPlace.enumerated() {
        print(placeLibrary.testPlace[idx])
    }
}
```

My CSV file is upload here : http://apps.e-rochoise.fr/ressources/imageTest.csv

And the print in my `printMyArray()` function give me nothing, but my print (`print("Line - Name : \(name) - Lat : \(lat) - Long : \(lon) - URL : \(url)")`) in my `downloadCsvFromURL()` give me all the value in the CSV line by line.

My Array is defined as follow :

```
    struct Place: Identifiable{
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        var lat: Double
        var long: Double
        var Name: String
        var url: URL
        var proximity: Double
        
        init (lat: Double, long: Double, Name: String, url: URL, proximity: Double){
            self.lat = lat
            self.long = long
            self.Name = Name
            self.url = url
            self.proximity = proximity
        }
        
        init(config: NewPlaceConfig){
            self.lat = config.lat
            self.long = config.long
            self.Name = config.Name
            self.url = config.url
            self.proximity = config.proximity
        }
    }
//Other File 
struct NewPlaceConfig{
    //var id = UUID().uuidString
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var Name: String
    var url : URL
    var proximity: Double
}
//Other File 
    class PlaceLibrary: ObservableObject{
        
        @Published var testPlace = [//Place]()
    }
```

So I don't understand why my line :

```
 let newPlace = Place(lat: Double(lat)!, long: Double(lon)!, Name: name, url: ((URL(string: url)) ?? URL(string : "NIL"))!, proximity: 0.0)
  placeLibrary.testPlace.append(newPlace)
```

Would not upload data into my array...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Each call of `PlaceLibrary()` creates a new instance. The instances in `downloadCsvFromURL` and `printMyArray` are different.

Comment: I'm not sur to understand .. Is it because I don't use a `@PublishedObject` ?

Comment: `placeLibrary` in `printMyArray` doesn't contain any places because it's not the same instance as in `downloadCsvFromURL`. It has noting to do with `@Published`.

Comment: Ok I see but how could I reach my data saved in my array in my `downloadCsvFromURL` function ?